# Process com,google.process.gapps stopped unexpectedly

Tags: sync

Started getting this error in the last few days. It is stopping various things like Gmail, Market and Listen from syncing.

I've read that it can be caused by bad data in records and that you should clear the data on the phone and then edit it on the server, but that's tricky if you don't know which item it is or even which app it is in.

Any suggestions? I've switched it off/on several times. The error occurs when I do just about anything in Listen and can't get my Gmail up at all. Only thing I noticed is that one podcast was showing some error in Listen. Dropped it from the queue, but still getting the problem.

HTC Tattoo on V1.6. Not rooted. No new apps added recently.

Comment: Which phone do you have?  Which Android version?  Is it rooted?  Stock firmware or custom ROM?  Did this start happening suddenly, or after installing some app?  Which troubleshooting steps have you already tried (e.g. factory reset)?

Comment: Added details above. Thinking I'll try a factory reset. Never done that before, but will back up any files I think I need.

Comment: I've done a factory reset now. Seems okay so far, but have to manually reinstall apps as I couldn't do a backup

Comment: Galaxy S (i9000), unrooted, same problem. Lots of apps...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn't find a reason for the error, but ended up doing a factory reset and since then everything has been fine. I had to reinstall my apps, but my Google data came back.

Comment: Since then I've used Cyanogen to get to 2.3